# Checking Resources Reservation Availability

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

i have the following table:

```
id | rsvp_date | return_date | user_id | car_id
```

where ID is the PK, rsvp_date & return_date is DATETIME, user_id & car_id is FK to user table and car table respectively.

What i want to do is to check everytime a user would like to make a reservation. The Query that checks that boils down to this (this query get's called by a function checkAvailability():

```
SELECT id
FROM `car_reservation`
WHERE ('2014-10-06 07:00:00' BETWEEN rsvp_date AND return_date)
AND car_id = 5;
```

The function i mentioned:

```
function checkAvailability($datetime, $id = null){
    $sql = "SELECT id
            FROM `car_reservation`
            WHERE ('".$datetime."' BETWEEN rsvp_date AND return_date)
            AND car_id = ".$id;

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    // echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->db->last_query());die();        
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Where the given date will be matched against rsvp_date and return_date columns. And the date is taken from a field in the form (there are 2 field; Start Date and Return Date).

The current code does not work as i want it to be. For example:

- Guest #1: Reserve Car A between 2014-10-06 07:00:00 To 2014-10-06
  10:00:00 [Valid]
- Guest #2: Reserve Car B between 2014-10-06 07:00:00
  To 2014-10-06 10:00:00 [Valid]
- Guest #3: Reserve Car A between
  2014-10-06 08:00:00 To 2014-10-06 11:30:00 [Unavailable, due to start
  time is not available]
- Guest #4: Reserve Car B between 2014-10-06 06:00:00 To 2014-10-06
  14:00:00 [Valid, but it is not suppose to be. Since Guest #2 already
  booked the car between 07:00:00 - 10:00:00].

Can anyone help me on how should i improve my code, so that the last condition will return False when there is already a booking made in between the requested reservation?

PS: I found this article but having a difficulty understanding it, i am looking for a similar approach only simpler. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

EDIT:

This picture visualize everything, i think now i just need to implement a function as specified on each column header (those who has check mark).

[image]

Comment: You only check for one specific timepoint `2014-10-06 07:00:00` and this is between `2014-10-06 06:00:00` and `2014-10-06 14:00:00`. So everything works correct. But you have to check the begin and end date of the planned reservation.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER i think i understand your concept, i just don't know how should i do it. Do i have check the begin and end date of the planned reservation against every hour range?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) you have to check different:

```
$query = "
    SELECT id
    FROM `car_reservation`
    WHERE (
        '".$datetimeStart."' <= return_date 
        AND 
        '".$datetimeEnd."' >= rsvp_date 
    ) AND car_id = ".$id
";
```

See SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d818c/1

Where `$datetimeStart` is `2014-10-06 06:00:00` and `$datetimeEnd` is `2014-10-06 14:00:00` as of your `Guest #4` test case scenario.

And be aware of SQL injections if you concatinate the SQL query with variables which may contain user input.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. And thanks again for the suggestion, the variable has been sanitized prior to query making.

Comment: I run tested your query, and strangely it returns with this: 9, 2014-10-15 07:00:00, 2014-10-15 17:00:00, 1, 5 and this 10, 2014-10-07 07:00:00, 2014-10-07 09:00:00, 1, 5

Comment: Okay, I mistyped something. Now check the sqlfiddle.